# Todo list, having difficulty getting both buttons to work

Tags: javascript, dom

I am just stuck on getting everything to work in my todo list.  Where I am at the moment is that when a new todo is added I need one button to toggle that it is completed, and the other button to remove the item.  It seems as though I am forgetting or not understanding the proper methodology to allow both buttons to be able to target the item.  I can only get one to work and not both.

I am still new JavaScript and all this, I am trying to complete this exercise for my coding bootcamp and have been stuck on this todo list for over a week now.

Sorry if I am not formatting this correctly, first time posting here and based on how difficult this is going, I am going to be getting a lot of practice.

```js
todoForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let newTodos = document.createElement("li")
  newTodos.innerText = document.querySelector("#add-el").value
  newTodos.classList.add("item")

  todoUl.appendChild(newTodos);

  let completedBtn = document.createElement("button");
  completedBtn.innerText = "✔️"
  completedBtn.classList.add("completed-Btn");
  completedBtn.type = "button"
  newTodos.appendChild(completedBtn)
  console.log(completedBtn)

  let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
  deleteBtn.innerText = "️"
  deleteBtn.classList.add("delete-Btn");
  deleteBtn.type = "button"
  newTodos.appendChild(deleteBtn)
  console.log(deleteBtn)

  newTodos.addEventListener("click", function() {
    newTodos.style.textDecoration = "line-through"
  })

  newTodos.addEventListener("click", function() {
    newTodos.removeChild()
  })
  //can not get the delete button to work

  todoForm.reset()
  console.log(newTodos)
})
```

Comment: why are you binding the event on the LI and not the button elements?

Comment: I suppose my thought process is that I am targeting the text on the LI.  I still get very crossed up at times.  Thank you for pointing that out.  It's unfortunately not the first time I have attempting to target the wrong thing.

Comment: This adds event listeners every time the event listener fires - which the formatting update shows clearly; - likely not what you wanted here.  Please update the snippet with HTML that reproduces your issue here.

Comment: FWIW adding anything in a "submit "handler is not a good thing since it goes away on the submit action.

Answer (score 0):

You're just setting the event listeners on the wrong element.

```
newTodos.addEventListener("click", function() {
    newTodos.style.textDecoration = "line-through"
})

newTodos.addEventListener("click", function() {
    newTodos.removeChild()
})
```

You're setting both listeners on the `newTodos` element instead of the individual buttons, like so:

```
completedBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    newTodos.style.textDecoration = "line-through"
})

deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    newTodos.remove()
})
```

Also, you need to call `newTodos.remove()` instead of `newTodos.removeChild()`

Comment: Thank you for the input, I tried but unfortunately still the same result, the delete button is not functioning.  Just as before I can cross-out the text but delete does nothing.

Comment: @Pmbyrd I've updated the answer to fix the delete button

Answer (score 0):

Got some help from my mentor, so with the help of the first answer posted I changed the targets for the event listener after we realized that I was not targeting the parent for the removeChild, nor was I passing in an argument.

```
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(deleteBtn)
    todoUl.removeChild(newTodos)
})
```